# JIRA works only on localhost

Tags: localhost, jira

Installed Attlassian JIRA on windows 7, and it works only on h_t_t_p://localhost:8088, but if i try to open it as h_t_t_p://127.0.0.1:8088/ or h_t_t_p://myipaddrees:8088/ - page doesn't open. Firewall swiched off.

h_t_t_p - should be http because of spam

Who can help me. Thanks.

Comment: How does writing out "h_t_t_p" help protect anyone from spam in this example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Docs](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Configuring+JIRA+Options)

> Base URL   The base URL of this JIRA installation. You can only configure JIRA to respond to a single URL and this setting must match the URL that your users request for accessing your JIRA site. You cannot (for example) have a different hostname or URL for internal and external users. This is especially important for JIRA 4.0.x or higher, as any mismatch between this Base URL setting and the URL requested by your JIRA users will cause problems with dashboard gadgets. This URL is also used in outgoing email notifications as the prefix for links to JIRA issues.

Comment: Can someone explain why this is the accepted answer when the linked documentation doesn't clearly articulate how to change the Base URL?

Comment: @Andrew because 5 years ago when I answered this question it was sufficient for the OP to solve their problem.